# Android 6.0: Positive Button of AlertDialog not working

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-6.0-marshmallow, huawei-mobile-services

For some reason, when clicking the positive button on an AlertDialog the dialog closes but none of the defined methods within the handler is executed.

Currently, this only happens on a Huawei-ALE-L21 running Android 6.0. For all other devices, the button click is registered and the app works like a charm.

Here is the code:

```
private void showDialog() {
    mInterface.getAlertDialog(getString(R.string.for_your_safety), getString(R.string.for_your_safety_text), true)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.allright, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { //method implementation

                }
            })
            .setNeutralButton(R.string.read, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { //method implementation

                }
            })
            .create()
            .show();
}
```

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: what is mInterface

Comment: mInterface is the reference to the activity, where the alertDialog is initiated.